# Swift 3 to Swift 4: FirebaseApp must be configured (when it is)

Tags: ios, swift

This is the error:

```
2017-11-08 21:56:14.897695-0200 htchhkr-development[4861:265024] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
```

This is where it loads:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
```

FirebaseApp use to be FIRApp, but Swift told me gently that it's no longer called FIRApp, but rather FirebaseApp. I renamed, but now I get that error.

What to do here?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. I migrated to swift 4 and ran my program and got the same error. I then ran pod update in terminal and that seemed to fix my problem.